# Estoy usando una librería en angular llamada ngx-typed-js para hacer un efecto de escritura en la pag. funciona pero en la consola sale un error

Tags: javascript, html5, nodejs, angular

Este es mi código HTML aquí estoy utilizando las propiedades de **ngx-typed-js** y ya he importado el paquete al módulo y también lo he exportado, que era todo lo que pedía.

```
<div class="preloader" *ngIf="!load">
    <img src=".././assets/images/logo.gif" alt="">

    <div class="div-container">
         <ngx-typed-js
         [strings]="['Hola soy Ralph Ortega y soy Front end Developmet bienvenido a mi portafolios']"
         [typeSpeed]="90"
         [startDelay]="1000" 
         class="typed">
           <h1 class="typing"></h1>
        </ngx-typed-js>
    </div>

</div>
<div *ngIf="load">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Como ven aquí mi aplicación compiló perfectamente :

```
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files   | Names     |      Size
vendor.js             | vendor    |   4.30 MB
polyfills.js          | polyfills | 484.63 kB
styles.css, styles.js | styles    | 418.46 kB
main.js               | main      |  67.79 kB

1 unchanged chunks

Build at: 2021-02-09T17:33:02.517Z - Hash: 319607b398b2e303bddd - Time: 10618ms

√ Compiled successfully.
```

Este es el error que me muestra por consola, ojo el código funciona pero aún así muestra este error.

> **PD:** En la documentación no dice nada de que tengo que agregar una clase o algo para que funcione.

```
    
    Error: src/app/preload/preload.component.html:6:10 - error TS2341: Property 'strings' is private and only accessible within class 'NgxTypedJsComponent'.
    
    6          [strings]="['Hola soy Ralph Ortega y soy Front end Developmet bienvenido a mi portafolios']"
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      src/app/preload/preload.component.ts:5:16
        5   templateUrl: './preload.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component PreloadComponent.
    src/app/preload/preload.component.html:7:10 - error TS2341: Property 'typeSpeed' is private and only accessible within class 'NgxTypedJsComponent'.
    
    7          [typeSpeed]="90"
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      src/app/preload/preload.component.ts:5:16
        5   templateUrl: './preload.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component PreloadComponent.
    src/app/preload/preload.component.html:8:10 - error TS2341: Property 'startDelay' is private and only accessible within class 'NgxTypedJsComponent'.
    
    8          [startDelay]="1000"
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      src/app/preload/preload.component.ts:5:16
        5   templateUrl: './preload.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component PreloadComponent.
```

> Esto es lo que pone mi archivo .ts a petición de un usuario pero este no pone nada que yo considere a tomar en cuenta pero claro esto también puede ser por mis inexperiencia en el tema.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-preload',
  templateUrl: './preload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./preload.component.css']
})
export class PreloadComponent implements OnInit {
  public load = false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.load = true;
    }, 110); /*11000*/
  }

}
```

Comment: Coloca lo que tienes en tu `component.ts`. Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: ¿Has importado en tu módulo principal el módulo este que estás usando? Está detallado en la documentación: https://github.com/thevladeffect/ngx-typed-js

Comment: Muchas gracias por la lectura recomendada y desde ya te expreso mis mas sinceras disculpas, hare todo lo posible por mejorar y no voy a tomar como excusa lo de ser nuevo. PD: eh leído el articulo desde que vi tu recomendación.

Comment: Por supuesto que lo eh importado a mi modulo principal, al principio de mi resumen digo esto.

Comment: Descuida hermano, eres nuevo en la plataforma, los que llevamos más tiempo estamos para guiarlos en un buen proceso, con la mejor de las intenciones :D